# pingfederate as a adfs claim provider

Tags: adfs2.0, adfs

I'm trying to setup PingFederate as a claim provider in ADFS with the intention that I federate from a PF realm through ADFS to an ADFS RP. I want ADFS to add attributes from Active Directory to the assertion before sending it to the RP. PingFederate is only sending the user's Windows login ID. On the Claim Provider side I'm passing through Name ID. Just for testing, I have tried adding an attribute like this:

c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"]
 => add(Type = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", Value = "myemail@test.com");

I added this on the CP side both above and then below my pass through rule and nothing was added to my assertion. I also tried this on the RP side with no luck.

I guess my question is whether this is possible in ADFS. Ultimately I would like PingFed to send the user's login ID as the name ID, have ADFS lookup the user in Active Directory and add the email address as a claim then send the assertion to the RP. As for adding the attribute from Active Directory, I found this post technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678048.aspx. Problem is I can't even add a manual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. My first use case is to ensure that the AD account exists.

Essentially what is required are 3 claim rules on the CP side:

1 - perform the lookup based on the name ID. I created a custom rule to

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier"]
 => add(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/primarysid"), query = "sAMAccountName={0};objectSID;{1}", param = c.Value, param = "MYDOMAI\" + c.Value);
```

The parameters required in for the query are:

- LDAP query to locate the user
- Attribute(s) to extract
- User's login ID in the format DOMAIN\userid

2 - a claim rule to simply pass the name ID through

3 - a claim rule to simply pass the SID through

On the RP side, I have 2 claim rules to pass the name ID and the SID through. Then I have an Issuance Authorization Rule to ensure that the SID is present as a claim. This is a custom rules with the following:

```
EXISTS([Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/primarysid"])
 => issue(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/permit", Value = "PermitUsersWithClaim");
```

Seems convoluted but this is what I have. My second use case is to ensure the account is enabled, but I'm not sure if this is possible because the disabled attribute is stored as a bit in the userAccountControl attribute.

Comment: For the second use case - you can't using a claims rule - you can by writing a custom attribute store - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee895358.aspx

Comment: Thank you for that link. I also found this link that talks about using Powershell as an attribute store - http://www.theidentityguy.com/articles/2011/11/19/powershell-attribute-store-for-ad-fs-20.html

Answer (score 0):

For a manual value, use something like:

```
=> issue(type = "http://contoso.com/partner", value = "Adatum");
```

For the query, use something like:

Use the normal LDAP rule to produce a loginID claim and then

```
c:[Type == "http://company.com/claims/loginID", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
=> issue(store = "Active Directory", types = ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress"), query = ";email;{0}", param = c.Value);
```